# use Confluence-publisher-plugin in Jenkins to send build information to Wiki

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, confluence

I know there are some questions regarding this, but didn't get the right answer yet.

I am trying to use Confluence publisher plugin in Jenkins to send build information (Logs, artifacts...) to wikiD page. I can attach artifacts and write plain text to the wiki page. But I'm trying to update/append/prepend wiki page **table** with build info. I think I might be able to achieve this by using macros but not sure how to use that for data in tables??

does anyone here know how to achieve that?

Comment: Nevermind, i found out the solution.

Comment: It would be good to answer your own question so others who may wind up here from Google also know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. I can mention how i did it. There might be different way others will do the same thing.

So, in Confluence, either create a Blank macros as mentioned on Confluence-publisher-plugin wiki and in Jenkins, use "Wiki Markup Replacements" options in plugin configuration to direct your Contents.

**OR** other option is what i did on mine, was to create table in the wiki and use **Cell header ( |cell1||cell2|... )** as **Marker Token**. then select plain text option, where you enter all the contents that you want to be published in your Wiki.

Comment: Can you post complete example using cells I'm trying to achieve the same thing right now.

Comment: @nslinux/@filip-stefanov, please let me know if you were able to append the cell value using tokens and if so, how did you achieve that. Thanks